# Multiple Values does not work when field widget is "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)"

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

In Drupal 7, multiple values does not show for fields which are "Autocomplete term widget (tagging)"

Please look at the attached screenshot. [image]

I'm trying to make 3 separate tags,
and want it to appear as the following:

Payment accepted:
**Interac**, **cash**, **Watcard**

But I'm not able to do so using commas. It works as plain text but I need it to be linked separate tags. Is there an easy solution to this? I'm new to drupal and don't really know much about coding.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the field widget to "Check boxes/ Radio buttons"[image]

For letting user select multiple values, go to Administration » Structure » Taxonomy » Your-Term » Manage fields, set Number of Values in Field Settings to "Unlimited"
[image]